# Selector in a List/GridView not displayed

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a GridView with a custom adapter, and when I select an item from the list, the selector is shown for a second and disappears. I guess the custom adapter causes it, and I tried playing with it and the selector, but to no avail.

Here's my adapter (based on the Grid View sample in "Hello, Views"):

```
package shira.android.paintdroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

class PaintActionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;
private int[] actionsImagesResources;

public PaintActionsAdapter(Context context)
{
    if (context==null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The context must be non-null!");
    this.context=context;
    /*actionsImagesResources=context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.
            actions_images);*/
    actionsImagesResources=new int[6];
    for (int counter=0;counter<actionsImagesResources.length;counter++)
        actionsImagesResources[counter]=R.drawable.pencil;
}

public int getCount() { return actionsImagesResources.length; }

public long getItemId(int position)
{ return actionsImagesResources[position]; }

public Object getItem(int position) 
{ return actionsImagesResources[position]; }

public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView actionImageView;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        actionImageView=new ImageView(context);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams=new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.
                FILL_PARENT);
        actionImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        //actionImageView.setAlpha(0);
    }
    else actionImageView=(ImageView)convertView;
    actionImageView.setImageResource(actionsImagesResources[position]);
    return actionImageView;
}
}
```

And here's the layout:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/paint_actions_grid" android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:numColumns="2" 
        android:layout_weight="0.15" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/> <!-- android:background="@color/ui_background_color"/> --> 
        <!-- android:listSelector="@drawable/actions_list_selector"/> -->
```

Thanks for any help.

Here's an image capture of how the GridView looks like now (for now, all the items have the same image). I want a frame in some color to be drawn around the selected image, but I get an orange rectangle that disappears after a second, as I said.

[image: Screen capture of the grid view]

Comment: can you post images of what it looks like now and maybe what you are trying to get it to look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because in touch mode there is no such thing as selected.  See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html).

You can get around this by setting your grid-cell layout to clickable `android:clckickable="true"` and then creating a ColorStateList as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html).

The state you want to use for this is `activated`.  Use that state in your selector xml.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/your_activated_color" />  
    <item android:color="@color/your_standard_color"/> 
</selector>
```

Then set the selector xml  as your background for the gridview cell layout.  That should achieve the desired effect.